# WebContext is no longer honoured after migration from Jboss7 to WildFly10

Tags: java, web-services, ejb, wildfly

I am migrating a statless EJB exposed as a web service from JBoss7 AS to WildFly 10 (granted I am a bit late).

The web service used to be accessible by http://localhost:8080/vmwWS/vmw, moving to WildFly gets me http://localhost:8080//vmwWS/WSVMWBean and I haven't found a way to change this.

Here's the web service class

```
[...]
@Interceptors(TracingInterceptor.class)
@Stateless
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.mydomain.WSVMW")
@WebContext(contextRoot="/vmwWS", urlPattern ="/vmw", authMethod="BASIC", secureWSDLAccess = false)
@SecurityDomain("JBossWS")
@RolesAllowed({ "Read", "Write" })
public class WSVMWBean implements WSVMW {
[...]
```

The Interface:

```
[...]
@WebService(name = "vmw")
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT)
@Local
public interface WSVMW {
[...]
```

And the jboss-webservice.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<webservices xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee/jbossws-web-services_1_0.xsd"
version="1.1">
  <context-root>vmwWS</context-root> 
   <port-component>
    <ejb-name>WSVMWBean</ejb-name>
    <port-component-name>WSVMWBean</port-component-name>
    <port-component-uri>/vmw</port-component-uri>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  </port-component>
</webservices>
```

The logs say:

```
22:16:59,520 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.cxf.metadata] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBWS024061: Adding service endpoint metadata: id=WSVMWBean
 address=http://localhost:8080/<ejb-jar-name>/vmwWS/WSVMWBean
 implementor=com.mydomain.WSVMWBean
 serviceName={http://vmw.mydomain.com/}/vmwWS
 portName={http://vmw.mydomain.com/}WSVMWBeanPort
 annotationWsdlLocation=null
 wsdlLocationOverride=null
 mtomEnabled=false
```

How do I get the previous behaviour back?

Comment: After some more investigation the jboss-webservice.xml gets ignored. I was able to change the second part of the address to /vmwWS/vmw by adding

    @WebService(name="vmwWS/vmw", endpointInterface = "com.mydomain.WSVMW")

to the web service stateless bean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cut it short this is the diff which fixed it:

```
-import org.jboss.wsf.spi.annotation.WebContext;
+import org.jboss.ws.api.annotation.WebContext;
```

From here:
https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBossWS4MigrationGuide